# Faking fog S3 file copy

Tags: unit-testing, amazon-s3, fog

I can't seem to reproduce a file copy in a testing environment.  I'm trying to test that I can set the content type of a Fog AWS S3 file, but it looks like the file isn't changing when I try to update it.  It works when not mocking.

```
Fog.mock!

file = fog_dir.files.create(:key => "image.png", :public => true)

options = {
  'Content-Type' => "image/png",
  'x-amz-metadata-directive' => 'REPLACE'
}
file.copy file.directory.key, file.key, options

# Failing
fog_dir.files.head(file_name).content_type.should eql "image/png"
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source for the `copy_file` mock](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/aws/requests/storage/copy_object.rb#L47-L76), it looks like this is indeed a bug in the Fog mocks as of 1.20.0; notice how it `.dup`s the source object, but doesn't take anything out of the `options` hash into account other than `x-amz-acl`.

This is probably worth [filing a fog issue](https://github.com/fog/fog/issues)!